# Search in list of class propertie-values where equal to a property set values

Tags: c#, linq

I try to get a new list of myClass where their properties are equal to a dummy class property set. I don't know how i write a linq expression what can do this.
Specially the list is came from EntityFramework, so if it not necessary I don't want to pull all the data at once.

Like:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public int MyInt { get; set; }
        public string MyString { get; set; }
        public bool MyBool { get; set; }
        public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    }

    public List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="myClass">A Dummy Class where stored the searched values</param>
    /// <param name="searchingPropertiesName">a string array where stored the searched property names</param>
    public void MySearch(MyClass myClass, string[] searchingPropertiesName)
    {
        var propInfo = new List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>();

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo myClassProp in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            foreach (string searchPropName in searchingPropertiesName)
            {
                if (myClassProp.Name != searchPropName)
                {
                    return;
                }

                propInfo.Add(typeof(EventSeries).GetProperty(searchPropName));
            }
        }


        var searchedList = myClassList.Where(e => e... "e.Property values are equal propInfo.values");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to compare one specific property, or all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version I wrote below will only really work properly with Linq-to-Objects. While an interesting academic problem, you should not use this approach in production. Your idea for dynamic predicates using a prototype value and a named list of properties does not translate into Linq-to-Entities (it will not generate good SQL). I suggest you instead build a query dynamically (using `IQueryable.Where`, and look for LinqKit).

```
private static readonly Dictionary<String,PropertyInfo> _properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().ToDictionary( pi => pi.Name );

public IEnumerable<MyClass>Search(MyClass prototype, IEnumerable<String> propertiesToFilter, IEnumerable<MyClass> items) {

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> selectedProperties = propertiesToFilter
        .Select( name => _properties[ name ] )
        .ToList();

    return items
        .Where( i => selectedProperties
            .Select( pi => pi.GetValue( i )
            .SequenceEquals( _selectedProperties
                .Select( pi => pi.GetValue( prototype ) )
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank your time and answer it is a good solution.
I think a little more, and yes i don't want to use it in production, so searching alternative solutions, and I decide to use the "generic repository pattern", with "automapper".